# On discrete logarithm problem.

Tags: computational-complexity, discrete-logarithms

$g$ generates $\Bbb Z_p$ and $g$ is not a quadratic resiude.

Supposing $g^{qz}=h\pmod p$ where $p=2q+1$ is prime and $q$ is prime and $z$ is even then $h=1\bmod p$. So we cannot find what $z$ was.

Supposing $g^{qz}=h\pmod p$ where $p=2q+1$ is prime and $q$ is prime and $z$ is odd then can we find $z$ in polynomial time (or are we still stuck with sieve techniques)?

Comment: $g^q \equiv \left(\frac{g}{p}\right) \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$ (unless $g \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$), you're out of luck whether $z$ is even or odd.

Comment: aw really?? why is it $-1\pmod p$?

Comment: It can be $\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, if $g$ is a quadratic residue. By Fermat's theorem, if $p \nmid g$, then $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. But $p-1 = 2q$, hence $(g^q)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, which implies $g^q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what if $g$ is not a quadratic residue and $g$ generates $\Bbb Z_p$?

Comment: Then $g^q \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. An thus $g^{qz} \equiv -1\pmod{p}$ for all odd $z$.